# ADOX on Windows 2008 server x64 Error

Tags: c#, 64-bit

I try to run Console Application that connects to Microsoft Access Database on the Windows 2008 server x64 and have this error:

```
Class not registered
   at ADOX.CatalogClass.Create(String ConnectString)
```

All works fine on the Windows XP x86.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixing this bug, application should be compiled for x86 CPU. And after that it will run on the x64 platform as a x86 app.

Answer (score 0):

ADOX COM component is only available for x86 systems. This means that it cannot be used on code that is generated for the x64 platform. A possible solution is to explicitly set the target processor in the Visual Studio project to x86.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for this bug after google it.

The problem is due to JET. JET doesn't have support for 64-bit. To fix this we changed App Pool configuration from 64-bit to 32-bit. That was all to fix this. Apparently, exception information is misleading.

**Application Pools->Select Your Application Pool-> Advanced Setting->Enable 32-Bit Applications ->True**

After done this, it is working correctly.